# Xamarin ios can't find default-568@2x

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I can't even compile the default project from visual studio. I created a new project from the new project menu in a fresh directory, changed the app identifier to my apple developer app name, and compile, and it tells me that Default-568@2x.png does not exist.

here is the full error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Users/boemanation/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/OpenGL_Xamarin_TestiOS/ddf7db6bef3b320db45c7f9f5fb4bd29/obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/Default-568h@2x.png does not exist
File name: '/Users/boemanation/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/OpenGL_Xamarin_TestiOS/ddf7db6bef3b320db45c7f9f5fb4bd29/obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/Default-568h@2x.png'
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) <0x34bb690 + 0x002ff> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) <0x34bb578 + 0x000c7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () <0x34bad88 + 0x00227> in <filename unknown>:0    OpenGL_Xamarin_Test.iOS`

I am completely stumped. any ideas?

Comment: I have a temporary fix, which was changing all the bundled resources to embedded resources. I'm not sure if this is considered acceptable, but it works for now. please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

project > properties > disable "Optimize PNG images files for iOS"

This is a workaround to solve this issue.